# Casting positive 'int' to 'size_t'

Tags: c++, casting, int, size-t

The difference between size_t and int is well-documented, which I recapitulate: the former is an alias to some unsigned integer type that's implementation-dependent, whereas the latter is signed; the former is preferable for memory declarations, whereas the latter is better for arithmetic operations.

My question is, if I do some arithmetic computations to give an int (which is never too large and is always positive) and assign it to a size_t variable (that's used for accessing array locations), is there any situation in which a problem may arise?

Comment: Prefer to use `unsigned int` in your calculations if you know the quantity will not be negative.  For example, the number of pages in a book, is never negative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assigning a signed type to an unsigned type is *always* well-defined (even for negative values). If the signed variable is no larger than the unsigned type, and has only non-negative numbers the value will not change in such a conversion.